# Unusual "crontab -e" bug

Tags: linux, bash, vim, cron

Ever since yesterday, whenever I try to edit my crontab with "crontab -e", instead
of taking me to the VIM editor with my cronjobs open, it opens a VIM editor of some random empty file named [No name]. Here is an image:

[image]

After exiting the VIM file with ":x", I am taken finally to the VIM editor of the cronjobs as expected. Then pressing ":x" again for example would exit me out.

Any ideas on why this is happening? This started happening after yesterday, unfortunately I can't remember what I did to cause this.

Comment: Sounds like you did something funky with your `.vimrc`. I'd ask on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Just rename the file .vimrc to summat else and get back to basics

Comment: Ed, you are on to something. I renamed .vimrc and then crontab -e performed as expected. I renamed it back and it failed again. What do you mean by "and get back to basics"?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang if you have a backup or earlier version of your `.vimrc`, try with that and diff with the latest to find which settings breaks it. Also, when the empty file appears, isn't there an error message in the status bar of vim?

Comment: Ok more updates guys, I found out that in the .vimrc it was the line that sets my theme to solarized which causes this.. Not sure why though because on other machines it does not. Also @janos, the error I get is "E32: No file name". I really appreciate you all helping so far, i'll try to upvote/give u all a ton of points for this!!

Comment: In the VIM window on the first empty file with no name, even when I enter ":w saveAsThis" and save the file and leave, when I call "crontab -e" again, another new empty file comes up

Comment: Getting the exact same issue with solarized theme in .vimrc after moving to centos linux whereas it was working find on Ubuntu. Were you able to find a solution to this?